# Need to sum enum values with another class field in a POST request

Tags: java, json, spring, list, enums

I have an Ingredients ENUM with Double type values:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Ingredients
    LETUCE(0.40),
    BACON(2.00),
    BEEF(3.00),
    EGG(0.80),
    CHEESE(1.50);
```

I have a Burger class with fields:

```
       Long id;
       String name;
       
       Double price;
       List<Ingredients> aditionalIngredients;
```

The class Burger has a `List<Ingredients> aditionalIngredients` field for aditional ingredients, I need to sum an aditional ingredient value to the default Burger price in a JSON POST request, for example:

```
{
  "name" : "Burger1",
  "price" : 5.00,
  "aditionalIngredients: ["LETUCE", "EGG"] //sum these 2 values to the burger default price 
}

EXPECTED RETURN

{
  "name" : "Burger1",
  "aditionalIngredients: ["LETUCE", "EGG"]
  "price" : 6.20         //0.40 + 0.80 + 5.00(burger price)
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
if(!burger.getAditionalIngredient().isEmpty()){
         for( Ingredients a : Ingredients.values()){
         burger.setPrice(burger.getPrice() +  a.getValue());
   }
}
```

But returned the sum of ALL THE ENUM values, not just ["LETUCE", "EGG].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're iterating over all the Ingredients

```
for (Ingredients a : Ingredients.values()) {
```

Try

```
for (Ingredients a : burger.getIngredients()) {
```

As a side note, consider renaming your enum `Ingredient` instead of `Ingredients` because a single instance represents an `Ingredient`, not all.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I'm going to practice more, ty!